# SAS Enterprise Miner - never get check mark until close and reopen project

Tags: sas, enterprise-miner

Relative newb to sas enterprise miner.  Whenever I run a node I almost never get the green check mark and the status bar at the bottom shows running.  However, if I close and reopen the project the check mark shows and then I can proceed.

Any idea what is wrong with my set up that causes this.  It's really annoying to have to continually close and reopen the project to be able to proceed.

Comment: I don't use Enterprise Miner but does the project contain SAS code that you have written?  Is it possible you are calling some SAS procedure and never ending the procedure so that it looks like the procedure is still running?  Many analysis procedures support RUN groups and require a QUIT statement to end the procedure.

Comment: good thought but no not in my case.  I have not written any code but just using the default nodes so far.